# How to select rows which are in russian?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with messages, something like this

```
id   message
1     hi
2     ok
3     துய
4     нет
```

In result I want to get only the fourth row, since the first 3 ones are written in different language

Comment: a form of solution is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956279/language-detection-with-data-in-postgresql

Comment: @VynlJunkie I can't use external libraries(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for certain ranges of characters.

For example, this query checks if the string contains a Cyrillic letter:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable
WHERE message ~ '[АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя]';
```

Comment: I get the following mistakes: 
1.Unicode escape values cannot be used for code point values above 007F when the server encoding is not UTF8 at or near "'[\u0400"
2.ERROR: character 0xd080 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "WIN1251"

Comment: Then you will have to enumerate the letters. You should use `UTF8`, however.

Answer (score 1):

You may try some crude language detection via letter unigrams.  This is extensible to cases where character ranges cannot be used to neatly disambiguate languages (e.g.: Latin languages).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=800ac14e82e39c4efdc5a4f1ca166db8&hide=1) is a working gist of this.

Basically:

```sql
create table charfreq (
    c text,
    f float,
    lang text
    );
insert into charfreq values
 ('а',  8.04,  'ru'),
 ('б',  1.55,  'ru'),
 ('в',  4.75,  'ru'),
...
 ('a',  8.167, 'en'),
 ('b',  1.492, 'en'),
 ('c',  2.782, 'en'),
...
 ('ï',  0.005, 'fr'),
 ('ô',  0.023, 'fr'),
 ('ù',  0.058, 'fr'),
 ('û',  0.06 , 'fr');
```

Then, assuming, e.g.

```sql
...
insert into test values
 (1, 'hi'),
 (2, 'ok'),
 (3, 'துய'),
 (4, 'нет'),
 (5, 'été');  -- a French message, just for fun
```

You can use:

```sql
select id, message, lang, score
from (
  select *, row_number() OVER (partition by id, message order by score desc) as rownum
  from (
    select id, message, lang, coalesce(sum(f), 0)/length(message) as score
    from (
      select *, unnest(STRING_TO_ARRAY(message, NULL)) as c from test
    ) as a
    left join charfreq b
    using (c)
    group by 1,2,3
  ) as a
) as a
where rownum = 1;
```

Outcome on the test table above:

| id | message | lang | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi | en | 6.53 |
| 2 | ok | en | 4.1395 |
| 3 | துய | *null* | 0 |
| 4 | нет | ru | 6.92 |
| 5 | été | fr | 3.41733333333333 |

**Notes**

The above is quite crude. A better approach is to use a proper [unigram language model](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/types-of-language-models-1.html). In [this other gist](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6db323415300f597b65418936fd12ffc&hide=1), we use such a model (using `sum(log(P))` instead of `prod(P)`), and a default probability (chars not matching) arbitrarily set to 0.01%. In that gist, notice how `'les aventures'` is correctly identified as French, whereas `'the adventures'` is (also correctly) decided to be English, even though the same `[a-z]` range is used.

**References**

- [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) for English and French letters unigram frequencies.
- [Source](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/letter-frequencies-various-languages/russian-letter-frequencies/) for Russian letter unigram frequencies.

Comment: Can't quite understand what to do with this outcome

Comment: Just select the rows `where lang = 'ru'`. This is additive to other answers because it can be generalized to other languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Table

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGE (
   Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   MESSAGE VARCHAR (50)
);
```

Values

```
INSERT INTO MESSAGE VALUES (1, 'hi');//False
INSERT INTO MESSAGE VALUES (2, 'ok');//False
INSERT INTO MESSAGE VALUES (3, 'துய');//False
INSERT INTO MESSAGE VALUES (4, 'нет');//True
INSERT INTO MESSAGE VALUES (5, 'нет-_*/?/()=.,123  ');//True
INSERT INTO MESSAGE VALUES (6, 'нет  123');//True
INSERT INTO MESSAGE VALUES (6, 'нет  123AAAA');//False
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM message m
WHERE 
ARRAY(SELECT ASCII(unnest(STRING_TO_ARRAY(REGEXP_REPLACE(M.message, '[^[:alnum:]]+', '', 'g'), NULL)))) <@ 
ARRAY(SELECT ASCII(unnest(STRING_TO_ARRAY('АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя0123456789', NULL))))
```

- Cyrillic alphabets : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabets
- Postgre SQL  Operator :
  https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-compare-arrays-in-postgresql
- String to ASCII :
  [PostgreSQL - Convert string to ASCII integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137674/postgresql-convert-string-to-ascii-integer)
- Array Function & Operators :
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html

Comment: But it won't work if mesage consisted symbols

Comment: you can replace or regex just for alphanumeric chars

Comment: Can you please give a clue how to do this?

Comment: with `REGEXP_REPLACE(M.message, '[^[:alnum:]]+', '', 'g')` . I updated my answer